# "permission denied" error despite having all needed file system permissions

Tags: android, permissions, adb, selinux

I'm on an android, using `adb shell` to troubleshoot an issue which my app has with the file system. I'm encountering a permissions error when using tinyalsa, so I wish to investigate the directories involved.

```
cannot open device '/dev/snd/pcmC1D0c': Permission denied
```

If I `su` and then `stat` each item in the path, the shell tells me the following permissions:

```
/         (755/drwxr-xr-x)
/dev/     (755/drwxr-xr-x)
/dev/snd/ (755/drwxr-xr-x)
```

If I try to `stat /dev/snd` without `su`, however, I get `Permission denied`.

Why would this be? I've even tried `su -c 'chmod -R a+rx /dev/snd'`, but that makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much in this area, but it appears that SELinux is interfering. If you disable it:

```
# In a "su" adb shell
printf 0 > /sys/fs/selinux/enforce
```

...you can experience the permissions that you see when you run `stat` as root.

This may not be the optimal solution, but it will allow you to perform the actions needed. I recommend reading up on SELinux if you are developing for anything but a very exclusive user base.